# Classifying according to relationship between variables

Tags: regression, classification, segmented-regression

I do have a large dataset and would like to classify it according to the relationship between some variables.

I do not want to use clusters, because clustering results groups that are similar. I do not need my groups to be similar, but I want them to have the same type of relationship between two predictors.

Example: I have a variable Cd which varies between 5 and 75. When Cd is low it is positively related with another variable, but this relationship is not evident anymore when the values get higher... However, when the values get still higher a weak negative relationship can be seen ... So what I would like to do is to separate the points where there is a positive correlation with the other variable, from the points where there is no relationship, from the points where this relationship is weakly negative.

At the end I would like to get (a) two linear regressions linking the two variables, one for the positive and one for the negatively correlated points and, most importantly (b) a separation of the points into  segments with positive, negative or no correlation with the other variable.

I need to do this many times for different variables and the points are not nicely following a trend, so it is not really possible to do this visually. Is there some kind of function for doing this?

Comment: Look for [tag:segmented-regression] instead of cluster analysis.